# Multi-targeting .NET 3.5 and .NET 4.0 with referenced assemblies

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I found a user whose hardware forces me to use .NET 4.0 instead of .NET 3.5 (video driver issue). However, most of my users do not have .NET 4.0. What are good ways of structuring my solution(s) so that I can target both. For this question, assume that I have a MyClass.dll project and a MyApp.exe. Both MyClass and MyProject need to be either .NET 3.5 or .NET 4.0.

Do I have make two solutions? Four projects? Configure output in a certain way? Use links? Thanks.  I'm guessing something like this might work (but is it best practice)

[image]

In this case, I make the output of both MyClass.dll, match the default namespace.

Comment: why can't you target 3.5 everywhere in this case? Or do you have features that need 4.0?

Comment: The .Net 4.0 runtime can run .Net 3.5 programs just fine, so can't you just target 3.5?

Comment: one of my users has a touch-enabled laptop - when the said laptop is connected to an external monitor, WPF AllowsTransparency causes a crash under 3.5 (but not under 4.0) -- don't ask me how many hours it took to debug this.

Comment: @tofutim - More than like this is not actually a problem with WPF 3.5, instead it's probably related to their display driver, and WPF 3.5 is just tripping over it.  You should make sure your client is running the most recent vendor driver for his display card.

Comment: Ahh, interesting possibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can deploy only once and modify App.Config [requiredRuntime element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a5dzwzc9.aspx)'s section in device that require .NET 4.0 runtime

Comment: Right, but I want to make sure that people who don't have .NET 4.0 don't have to download it, because we have many users overseas who will really suffer if they have to update the .NET version.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use features of .NET 4.0, you don't need two projects. You just need to compile two times and target a different framework each time.
You can find this option on the application tab of the project properties.

Don't forget to save the output files between two generations, or change the output path when you change the targeted framework.

Comment: The issue here is that his video card does not work properly with .NET 3.5 though it does with .NET 4.0. When AllowsTransparency is activated in a WPF window, it causes the whole application to crash when the window is shown.

Comment: For now on your best choice is to make a version of your software specially for this kind of graphic cards, in which you will not allow Transparency...